# Python Program how to count number of times the letter c shows up

Tags: python, count, char

**Assignment:**

Return the number of occurrences of character `c` in string `s`, 
ignoring case. Use loops. Do not use the in-built string method `count`, 
which does a similar thing. The idea is to learn to write loops. You 
should ignore case when comparing a character of `s` with `c`.

**My attempt:**

```
 def countletter(s, c): #BAD
     count = 0
     for c in s:
        if c == c:
        count += 1
        return count
```

Am I on the right track? I seem to get some assertion errors when I test it in the main...

Comment: Is "character c", the character "c", or a character represented by an argument called "`c`"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `return` is at wrong place. So your function is actually returning only after one iteration.

Also you should not use the variable name `c` in for loop, use some different variable, as it replaces the value of `c` recieved from the function call with the current character being fetched by the `for-loop`.

```
def countletter(s, c): #BAD
    count = 0
    for x in s:
        if x.lower() == c.lower():
            count += 1
    return count


print countletter("abcdefFf","F") #prints 3
print countletter("a","A")        #prints 1
```

Comment: I am still getting an assertion error assert(count letter("b", "c") == 0);

Comment: @billnobby try something like : `assert countletter("b","c")=="b".count("c")`

Comment: Okay that works for lower case letters but I also want it to count if its uppercase too.  The assert(count letter("a", "A")) == 1 ) should work as well and it doesn't

Comment: @billnobby use `if x.lower() == c.lower()`, to handle the UPPERCASE letters.

Comment: but I want it for both so do I have to do an else if conditional statement I want upper case too

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answers above, there is a built-in method count in Python. You can use it in your project, if this function isn't a homework etc.(Oh, i saw now, it is an homework. But additional information is harmless.:) )

```
"baris".count("b")
```

returns 1

Answer (score 0):

If you compare the variable `c` defined by `for c in s:` you are always going to get true. So, your comparison should look like `c == 'c'` (you can figure out how to do the case insensitive check) and your return is indented incorrectly

Comment: how does this work as say when I compare "a" and "a" the count returns as 0 but should return 1.

Comment: Din't notice c was in the argument AshwiniChaudhary has pointed you in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

The position of the return statement is wrong. Delete the four spaces (or a tab what you've used)

Answer (score 0):

Just as another example of a way to do this outside of the built-in `count()` method, one can use a generator expression and the `sum()` builtin:

```
>>> def countletter(s, c):
...     return sum(x.lower() == c.lower() for x in s)
... 
>>> countletter("abcdefFf", "F")
3
>>> countletter("a", "A")
1
```

What we do is produce a generator of `True` and `False`s (`True` where the character matches). `sum()` will then give us the count, as `True` is `1` in Python, and `False` is `0`:

```
>>> True == 1
True
>>> False == 0
True
```

Comment: Or possibly write it as: `sum(1 for x in s if x.lower() == c.lower())` which doesn't rely on that particular nature of booleans and IMHO reads more naturally