# python 3 Acess file and check number of time phrase comes up

Tags: python

I'm trying to check a TSV of results and want to see how many times F and S come up (for failure or success) however I'm not sure how to doing this counting, or how to having it search the file

I've come across something that is sort of what I'm looking for: [Python Program how to count number of times the letter c shows up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13103148/python-program-how-to-count-number-of-times-the-letter-c-shows-up)

```
def countletter(S, F): 
    count = 0
    for x in S:
        if x.lower() == F.lower():
            count += 1
    return count

print (countletter("abcdefFf","F"))
```

But it isn't perfect and I'm not sure how to make it search the file.

Comment: `open(filename).read()` gets you the contents of a file.

Comment: `print (countletter("abcdefFf","F")` which result is expected? 1 or 3? Example script will print 3.

Comment: Reishin I don't know I only took it from this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13103148/python-program-how-to-count-number-of-times-the-letter-c-shows-up

Comment: Do you need a count per line, or a count for the whole file?

Comment: count the whole file

Comment: @jonrsharpe ok then what level of knowledge do I need to use SO? all I've done is a lynda tutorial http://www.lynda.com/Python-3-tutorials/essential-training/62226-2.html

Comment: @Oliveratontoit I suggest you head to the Help Center via http://stackoverflow.com/tour and read up on how we expect questions to be asked

Comment: @jonrsharpe ok I've improved it, is it any better?

Comment: @Oliveratontoit no, frankly. What does *"it isn't perfect"* mean, exactly? Provide inputs and expected and actual outputs. *"I'm not sure how to make it search the file"* - which part of that is the problem? Do you know how to get the text from a file? How to pass things to functions? This is all pretty basic stuff; do some research.

Comment: @jonrsharpe no I don't now how to get the text from a file or to pass something to a function, all I've done is lynda videos. Why do you think I am here asking questions

Comment: If *"lynda videos"* don't cover this, find a better tutorial. Or, and this is probably a more useful skill, learn to decompose the problem (in this case: 1. open file; 2. get text from file; 3. pass text to function) and search how to do *each step separately* - these are all **extensively** covered on SO and elsewhere already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the count result applies to the whole file you can use a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

with open('input.tsv') as infile:
    counts = Counter(infile.read())

for c in 'SF':
    print '{}: {}'.format(c, counts.get(c))
```

This has the advantage of allowing you to obtain counts of any character (not just "S" and "F") with one pass of the file.

You could also just use [`str.count()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count) for a specific character (or a string), but if you need counts more than one character you'll find a `Counter` more convenient and probably faster too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the file contents to your `countletter` function.

```
with open("FILE_TO_OPEN_AND_READ.txt") as f:
    data = f.read()

print (countletter(data,"F"))
```

This opens and reads the file into `data`. For this example, I'm assuming your file is relatively small. Then `data` is passed into `countletter` as the first parameter, instead of a hardcoded string (`"abcdefFf"` in your example).

One note about your code, you are missing a closing parenthesis in your `print` statement. I've added that in my example above.